# Как добавить условие SUM в JOIN?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Имеются 3 сущности: ticket, metric и tag. Билеты, их теги и метрики. Есть следующий запрос:

```
Tag.select(
  "tags.id as tag_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT low.ticket_id) AS low,
  COUNT(DISTINCT high.ticket_id) AS high"
).joins(
  'LEFT JOIN metrics ON (
    tags_id = metrics.tag_id AND
    metrics.day = "07.10.2020" AND
    metrics.action = 4
  )
  LEFT JOIN metrics AS low ON (
    metrics.id = low.id AND
    low.priority_id = 1
  )
  LEFT JOIN metrics AS high ON (
    metrics.id = low.id AND
    high.priority_id = 2
  )'
).group('tags.name, tags.id')
```

Он выводит количество билетов для каждого тега c приоритетами low и high.
Например:

```
[
  {tag_id: 1, low: 12, high: 7},
  {tag_id: 2, low: 25, high: 5}
]
```

Возможно ли этот запрос изменить так, чтобы перед выбором билета сначала считалась сумма полей metrics.duration с metrics.action равными 1, 2 и 3 и выполнялось условие, что эта сумма больше 100?

То есть у нас есть билет и несколько его метрик. Мы складываем все duration в метриках с action равным 1, 2 и 3 и потом сравниваем эту сумму с 100. Если сумма больше 100, то такой билет засчитывается.

Comment: конечно. сделайте собственно этот запрос получающий сумму т.е. просто считаете сумму выбрав эти 3 акшена, только надо сгруппировать до того< что вам нужно, билета или еще чего (в вопросе недостаточно данных для понимая что точно нужно) добавляете к нему having sum(...) > 100. все он вам дал билеты или то что вам нужно с суммами >100, делаете обычный join этого подзапроса с остальным запросом. ну и подзапросы low и high конечно надо в один собрать, получать по отдельности незачем, если приоритет можно проверить уже внутри count

Comment: Ну вообще запрос - просто безобразный. Я допускаю, что этот ужас - продукт особенностей фреймворка, неспособного реализовать все возможности SQL в рамках своей формализации, но его надо переписывать с использованием условной агрегации - даже если в результате это получится стопроцентный rawSQL. Также не очень понятно - в SELECT имеется `tags.id as tag_id`, а в ON - `tags_id = metrics.tag_id`. То ли во втором случае опечатка, то ли в таблице tags несколько id-полей... неплохо бы показать структуры таблиц.